# How to query product is onsale today?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to query some product is onsale to day, here is my query args

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => $number,
    'orderby '          => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC'
);
$query_args['meta_query'] = array('relation'=> 'AND');
$query_args['meta_query'][0][] = array(
    'key'     => '_sale_price',
    'value'   => 0,
    'compare' => '=',
    'type'    => 'DECIMAL',
);
$query_args['meta_query'][0][] = array(
    'key'     => '_sale_price_dates_from',  
    'value'   => date("Y-m-d"),
    'compare' => '=',
    'type'    => 'DATE',
);
$query_args['meta_query']   = array_filter( $query_args['meta_query'] );
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: How do we know if something is wrong if you don't post any errors?

Comment: Hi! I resolved it! Thank you so much! 
- No errors show!

Answer (score 1):

I see it!

```
        $args = array(
            'status' => 'publish',
            'limit' => 1,
            'sale_price' => 0,
            'date_on_sale_to' => date('Y-M-D'),

        );
        $products = wc_get_products( $args );
```